# how to get filename based on the number of characters after the dot

Tags: php, regex

hello here is what I have :

```
filename mycoolfile.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAHy4rl_jpJF4Z70W1BQUgXf7IOvLXw
```

using php how do I capture the name of the file which would be anything.ext and get rid of the rest.
so return : `mycoolfile.zip`
I know it can be accomplished using regular expressions but I am not familiar with those, I am open to any suggestions or any way to accomplishing the task as long as it works for anyfilename.ext?blablablaafter

it doesnt matter if its regex or not as long as it works. any help please

Comment: Is the `?` always there? You could perhaps use substring and the index of the `?`.

Comment: yes its always there. any example on how to do it ?

Comment: Is it really that hard to use substring and get the index of `?` in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = '/lul/what/mycoolfile.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAHy4rl_jpJF4Z70W1BQUgXf7IOvLXw';
$file = basename(preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $path));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parse_url to get the name

```
<?php

$str = "mycoolfile.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAHy4rl_jpJF4Z70W1";
$parsed_url = parse_url($str);

echo $parsed_url["path"] . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `parse_url` function:

```
$u = 'filename mycoolfile.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAHy4rl_jpJF4Z70W1BQUgXf7IOvLXw';
$arr = parse_url($u);
echo $arr['path']; //=> OUTPUT: filename mycoolfile.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use '?' as a deliminator in `explode()` and use the value from an array, or perhaps use `preg_split()`?

edit: or use the much better solutions above! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this

```
$u = 'mycoolfile.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAHy4rl_jpJF4Z70W1BQUgXf7IOvLXw';

$url=explode("?",$u);
echo $url['0'];
```